# How to embed a mobile application in other application?

Tags: android, widget, embed

I'm building a mobile application for a company and I need to add in the company mobile application a button that go directly in a different application . 
Anyone know a solution to embed 1 mobile app in other app???

Comment: Please edit your question and explain completely and precisely what you mean by "embed 1 mobile app in other app".

Comment: I've edit my question. I'm building a mobile application for a company with our history, contacts, descriptions and products.
In addition to these functions I need to add a external mobile app that run in my application. What is a solution to embed an external mobile app in my ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the code of your button, you can launch an explicit/implicit [intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) that can launch another application (authored by someone else). The application won't be running inside your application, but to the user, he/she will have the illusion that the other application running is part of your own. This is assuming of course that the second application is already installed on the user's phone. If it isn't installed, your button can just fetch the relevant application's installation page from Google Play for the user to install the app, and then run the application once installed.

In your application, you can also provide a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to keep your data. A content provider provider exposes a set of public CRUD interfaces to your data for other applications to access. This is how the contacts database is shared on Android for instance between many different applications, even non-Google applications.

Basically, you first need start at the beginning and educate yourself on the [fundamentals of Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html). If you start reading about intents and content providers, those constructs may not make any sense to you until you first learn about Activities, the Activity's lifecycle, stacks/tasks, and the way security generally works on Android. You may even want to look on Youtube, there are some very good highly rated Google I/O videos on there that talk about the fundamental concepts of Android.

Comment: The minimum level is 8. But there is a way to do only one installation??

Comment: If you're the person installing both applications, then you're in luck -- it's even easier that way. You can just install one application that can look like two different applications to the user, but that will act just like one application in the background.

Comment: Again, you really need to educate yourself on the fundamentals of Android. You don't need to go in-depth, you just need to educate yourself a little bit on the very broad concepts first. That will save you so much time. I guarantee it.